# Where can over age 65 airline pilots fly?

Tags: pilots

Some countries have no maximum age for airline pilots while many other countries specify age 60 or 65. (Austria, Russia, Canada, Australia, etc., have no maximum age)

ICAO rules currently specify a max age of 65 which allows ICAO member states to fly into countries where the max age is only 60.

Does this rule apply to only landing and taking off, or also to in transit overflights?

For example, could a flight depart Canada, overfly American airspace, and fly to Australia with crew members older than 65?

If not, what about a flight from two bordering countries like Canada to Russia?

Comment: Part of this is covered in [this question/answer](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/15391/69) here on the site.

Comment: Where exactly is the Canada-Russia border?

Comment: @DJClayworth I assume OP is thinking of a polar route.

Comment: Yes, Russian airspace borders Canadian airspace.

Answer (score 1):

Pilot qualification- including age limit - is according to the law of the country where the aircraft is registered. What a pilot must abide by when flying overseas is the local operating/air traffic rules.

Comment: Sorry, that is not really correct.  ICAO rules allow the pilots of member states to fly into countries without meeting the age requirements of local countries. France for example has a max age of 60 yet airlines from all over the world routinely fly into France with pilots over age 60.