# Are pilots over the age of 65 allowed to act as PIC for ferry flights between the UK and Canada?

Tags: pilots, caa-uk-regulations, ferry-flight, pic

I have been informed that I'm not allowed to act as PIC for a ferry flight to and from the UK for a Canadian commercially-registered transport aircraft that I currently fly in Canada for charter ops.

Does anybody have experience with this scenario and can provide input?

I have been told it is only permitted for privately-registered aircraft. However, My current understanding is that the regulations would apply internationally based on the national authority that the aircraft is registered under.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! See [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/15391/62), it looks like ICAO limits international commercial operations to 60, or 65 if you have a younger pilot on board too.

Comment: For what it's worth I agree with your understanding. Australia doesn't have a mandatory pilot retirement age, and our pilots over that age are allowed to fly into countries with such a restriction, as long as they are on an Australian registered aircraft. But I have nothing to confirm that the same applies for your situation.

Comment: @Pondlife Note that this applies to "commercial air transport" operations, not just commercial operations (the question that you linked to specifically asks about Part 135).

Comment: I cannot answer for Canada, but I would guess that it is similar to US rules (most of them are), and the FAA has a rule which says that when you are flying outside of the US that you must comply with FAA rules AND with the laws in the country in which you are flying, as well as some of the ICAO guidance.  That being said, a ferry flight isn't typically a flight that falls under air carrier rules (in the US), so may be allowed.  I'll have to let someone with actual knowledge of Canadian rules provide an official answer though.

Comment: Ok thanks for input, I will be consulting with an aviation lawyer in the next few days who specializes in ICAO law and its application to Canada and other states.

Comment: @AlanVittery Please come back and let us know what the lawyer said!

Comment: @Lnafziger Good point! Hopefully it at least gives some context and helps the OP to ask the right questions with a lawyer.

Comment: Canada has no max age for any pilot, in any type of operation, in Canadian airspace.  So the question becomes “What is the max age for a pilot operating a Ferry flight of a commercial aircraft in the UK?”